# Substring with delimiter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return a substring of the following, it's comma delimited [only one comma]

```
City-City-City, State-State-State
```

Sometimes it's only one city and state, sometimes it's more than one of either [or  both]

Basically, I need to just return the state initials pass the comma.
What's the best way to do this? I'm looking into the substring function, but that doesn't seem that smart. I found a split function but it looks like overkill and I don't like to use code I don't understand.

Ex:

```
Cincinnati-Middletown, OH-KY-IN
Cleveland-Elyria-Mentor, OH
Abilene, TX
```

Output:

```
OH-KY-IN
OH
TX
```

Thanks for the answers;I just figured it out thanks to Sonam's starting point.
Here's what I got. Haven't looked into it but it seems to returning the right stuff.

`select substring(CBSAName,charindex(',',CBSAName)+1, LEN(CBSAName)) FROM CBSAMasterList`

Comment: Can you show us the expected results from the data set?

Comment: Thanks for the edit bluefeet. Forgot to wrap it up like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294893/how-to-connect-flutter-app-to-sql-server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select substring('Abilene, TX',charindex(',','Abilene, TX')+2,2)
```

Comment: Hey Sonam! Thanks for helping me out again. With charindex(',',','Abilene, TX') how do I... search and do the manipulation on my whole table of 5000+ stuff. At the moment, I'm only getting TX back. Can I put SELECT statements in charindex or substring?

Comment: What value are you exactly looking for?

Comment: Anything after the comma basically. I'm doing a query on 6000 entries and only care about the state they're in, which I know is after any comma.

Comment: In that case we can go for some larger value for substring function so that it can pick everything after the comma.
select substring('Cincinnati-Middletown, OH-KY-IN',charindex(',','Cincinnati-Middletown, OH-KY-IN')+2,300)

Comment: Here I've passed 300 as a second parameter for substring function which means it will pick up to 300 characters after the ','