# Flutter with Azure API connecting to SQL SERVER DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, flutter

I am developing a mobile app with Flutter, however my data sits in a sql sever database. Would I still be able to perform CRUD operations on that DB from a Flutter mobile app?

And are there any magical plugins for Flutter to achieve this ?

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way from my point of view is to do that is through http Requests, this means you need to

1. create a rest application on your azure API
2. the application will perform http requests(post-patch-delete-get)
3. each request of these will map to an operation on the database(get = read, post=create, patch=update, delete=delete)

Answer (score 3):

You can reference this blob: [How to connect Flutter App to sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294893/how-to-connect-flutter-app-to-sql-server) .

NTMS did that successfully with SQLServerSocket.

First: you need a SQLServerSocket: https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket is free and works!

Second: you need a client https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket (look in DartClient folder).

He tested it with his remote sql and is working on CRUD.

I think you can get more useful infromations from that blob.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @LukeVincent You're welcome. Can you accept my answer?Thanks and have a good day.